# Recaptcha always invalid on live site

Tags: php, captcha, recaptcha

The [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) seems to validate on my local machine, but it always fails when I upload it to my live site. I dumped the answer/response object, it looks like this:

```
ReCaptchaResponse::__set_state(array(
   'is_valid' => false,
   'error' => '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"',
))
```

There's HTML in it! What's going on, why is this failing?

I dumped my `$_POST` vars too, they look like this:

```
array (
  *snip*
  'recaptcha_challenge_field' => '03AHJ_VuvqpAkJnmfOZHHf80EPt85lVEeq9IRuO9zw1jZ1fzUk-_DAw0z2k3-TeXzAXQVXUWChyCGnC1RoXRPly4Ldz0FugPKW_WKWEoKysNLnpcv2xvyWONpq0VDV3ipsy5Vukui0zxlSqiBBWw00VYPSkO52OqMv_A',
  'recaptcha_response_field' => 'uterf sw',
)
```

---

Validation code:

```
$recaptcha_answer = recaptcha_check_answer('MY_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $_POST['recaptcha_challenge_field'],  $_POST['recaptcha_response_field']);

if(!$recaptcha_answer->is_valid) {
    $validation_errors[] = 'The reCAPTCHA you entered was not correct';
    echo '<!-- '.var_export($recaptcha_answer,true).var_export($_POST,true).' -->';
}
```

Display code:

```
<?= recaptcha_get_html('MY_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE') ?>
```

---

If I leave the recaptcha textbox empty and submit the form I get the proper error message:

> incorrect-captcha-sol

But if I fill it in, it always shows that doctype... I just noticed that that's not the doctype I'm using; is it trying to tell me I need to use a strict doc type and not transitional?

---

I'm using the "clean" theme if it makes any difference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'clean'
    };
</script>
```

The "red" one doesn't display correctly; the textbox is misaligned.

---

Did some poking into the library. There's a method called `_recaptcha_http_post`. It uses `fsockopen` to send a request to the validation server. Outgoing request looks something like this:

```
POST /recaptcha/api/verify HTTP/1.0
Host: www.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
Content-Length: 272
User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP

privatekey=<<MY INFO HERE>>&amp;challenge=<<BLAH>>...
```

But the response I get back doesn't look like it's from Google. It's a "Access forbidden!" page. I'm wondering if something is intercepting it...

Comment: Is this the Google reCaptcha? Also what code are you using to validate the captcha itself?

Comment: @Sammaye: Yes, Google recaptcha. Posting code now.

Comment: Ok, you say !$recaptcha_answer->is_valid, where is the else statement?

Comment: Hmm I use this exact code too and it works perfect for me....are you sure your private key is right?

Comment: @GundarsMēness: There is no else statement on that. Further down I check if the `$validation_errors` array is empty or not.

Comment: Did you specify your domain name when you obtained reCaptcha's keys? Or it was public?

Comment: @AzizAG: I chose a "global key". But the domain name is correct, albeit without `www.`

Comment: Try and var_dump the error object in the recaptcha lib itself before it is assigned as the class var, tell what this html document says

Comment: @Sammaye: Now we're getting somewhere! There's actually a full error page in there.... it's a permission error.

Comment: Aha so it must be something with the private key, hmm I wonder if reCaptcha API cares for subdomains, hopefully though it should say exactly what it doesnt like.

Comment: @Sammaye: No, I don't think that's it. I think it has to do with how my server is configured. There's an email address here; I ran a whois on it and it's someone else on my shared hosting. I don't know how it's hitting him, but I'm thinking he somehow screwed with some settings that's messing the rest of us up. Still investigating.

Comment: Poop :( I hate shared hosting for these reasons, APIs never function quite as they should and you normally have to fiddle around.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. Since the response wasn't coming back from Google, I tried looking up the IPs:

```
echo 'www.google.com: '. gethostbyname('www.google.com').'<br/>';
echo '<offending site>: '. gethostbyname('<offending site>');
```

They're the same when I run this on my server! Someone's screwed up the host lookup. Ugh!